# Managing Focus In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a autocomplete feature using React, and when the user selects an item on the list I want the input to update. My problem is when the input loses focus I want the menu to disappear unless the user selects the in the menu. Currently, showing the menu is based on a property called showDropDown. In the render method I have if showDropDown it builds the menu components. It seems that the render method is being called before the click listeners on the menu items, and is removing them before onClick is called.

```
handleOnBlur = () => {
  this.setState({ showDropDown: false });
};

handleOnFocus = () => {
  this.setState({ showDropDown: true });
};
handleRenderSubComponents = (options) => {
  ...
  return options.map((option) => {
    ...
    return (<li key={displayString} className={className}>
      <span onClick={() => {this.handleOnItemSelect(option, fieldInput);}} style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
        {displayString}
      </span>
    </li>);
  });
};
render() {
 ...
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <div>
        <input
          style={{ position: 'relative' }}
          disabled={disabled}
          ref={(inputElem) => {this.inputElem = inputElem;}}
          valueLink={{ value: this.state.value, requestChange: (value) => this.handleOnChange(value) }}
          onBlur={this.handleOnBlur}
          onFocus={this.handleOnFocus}
          onKeyUp={this.handleOnKeyUp}
        />
      </div>
      <ul className="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-justify" style={dropDownStyle} >
        {showDropDown && this.handleRenderSubComponents(options)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What I need to do is only hide menu if the input loses focus, but the focus is not in the menu

Comment: Where is the code that depends on the `showDropDown` state?

Comment: Not sure how that was missed on the copy over. Added back in

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you need. The key is that the onMouseDown event on the container is fired before the onBlur on the input.  So we set a class variable that can be check in the onBlur and if the container was clicked we force focus back to the input.  The setTimeout clears this variable again, so the order of execution will be onMouseDown, onBlur, setTimeout callback.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/905cL7xn/1/)

```
 class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    this.onInputBlur = this.onInputBlur.bind(this);
    this.onContainerMouseDown = this.onContainerMouseDown.bind(this);
    this.onOptionClick = this.onOptionClick.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      input: '',
      showList: false
    };

    this.options = ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3', 'Option 4'];
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.containerMouseDownTimeout);
  }
  onInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({input: e.target.value, showList: e.target.value.length > 2});
  }
  onInputBlur() {
    const showList = this.clickedInContainer && this.state.input.length > 2;

    this.setState({
      showList
    });

    if (showList) {
      this.input.getDOMNode().focus();
    }
  }
  onContainerMouseDown() {
    this.clickedInContainer = true;

    this.containerMouseDownTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.clickedInContainer = false;
    });
  }
  onOptionClick(option) {
    this.setState({
        input: option,
      showList: false
    })
  }
  renderList() {
    return (
      <ol style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>
                {this.options.map((o, i) => <li key={i} onClick={() => this.onOptionClick(o)}>{o}</li>)}
      </ol>);
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div onMouseDown={this.onContainerMouseDown}>
          <input ref={ref => this.input = ref} value={this.state.input} 
            onChange={this.onInputChange} onBlur={this.onInputBlur}/>
          {this.state.showList && this.renderList()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```